# Хранение, доступ и жизненный цикл данных необходимым для отрисовки

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, архитектура, графика

Имеется простая 2D игра с видом сверху и в профиль (как в Heroes of Might and Magic III). Игровая карта - тайловая, процедурно генерируемая, её размер - не ограничен. По мере перемещения персонажа подгружаются новые участки карты (чанки), другие удаляются.

Каждый объект, который должен отображаться на экране, содержит компонент GraphicsInfo, который в свою очередь хранит такие данные как позиция на экране, размеры и т.д. Идея заключается в том, чтобы в части программы, отвечающей за отрисовку, хранить коллекцию всех этих объектов удобным для отрисовки способом.

Но появилась сложность - при выгрузке чанков из памяти нужно как-то определять, какие именно объекты GraphicsInfo там находились и удалять их из коллекции.Все осложняется ещё тем, что загрузка и выгрузка чанков осуществялется в отдельном потоке. Поэтому хранить объекты в самих чанках и удалять их оттуда непосредственно при выгрузке не хотелось бы, т.к. задача сильно усложняется проблемой синхронизации разных потоков.

Вопрос: как проверить - какие объекты находились на выгруженных чанках? Хотелось бы чтобы код отвечающий за загрузку и выгрузку карты был как можно меньше связан с кодом отвечающим за отрисовку объектов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее, вы храните объекты (или ссылки на них, не суть) в чанках. Загрузили чанк - добавили его объекты к отрисовке. Выгрузили чанк - убрали его объекты из отрисовки.

Для упрощения, можете в каждом объекте добавить поле "к какому чанку он относится". Тогда удаление станет еще проще. Хотя, чанки обычно квадратные и вычислить чанк по расположению объекта проще простого.

Все операции по добавлению и удалению, естественно нужно делать в критических секциях (или других объектах синхронизации), во избежании ошибок.

Comment: "Выгрузили чанк - убрали его объекты из отрисовки". Извините - забыл упомянуть - загрузка и удаление чанков происходят в отдельном потоке, и чтобы избежать сложностей синхронизации не хотелось бы выполнять удаление объектов из чанков при их выгрузке.

Comment: "удаление объектов из чанков при их выгрузке" - вы что-то путаете, или зачем из чанков удалять объекты? Удаляете чанк - убираете его объекты из отрисовки. Что вызывает трудности? Приведите в вопросе пример проблемы?

Comment: Kromster, извините, не сразу вас понял. Вы предлагаете хранить все объекты в одном месте и к примеру каждый кадр игры проверять - находится ли объект в загруженном чанке или нет(а проще - на карте или нет). И если нет - удаляем его и его компоненты. Я ничего не напутал?

Comment: Нет, не верно. Я ***бы предположил***, что у вас есть чанки с объектами. Объекты этих чанков вы добавляете/удаляете из отрисовки по мере необходимости. В отрисовке, вы может быть держите список объектов (со ссылками или признаками из какого они чанка) и вероятно сортируете объекты для корректной очередности отрисовки (что ближе - поверх дальнего). И обновляете это все только по мере необходимости/изменениям.

Comment: Вы все верно поняли.

Comment: Выше вы писали: "Удаляете чанк - убираете его объекты из отрисовки" и "Все операции по добавлению и удалению, естественно нужно делать в критических секциях (или других объектах синхронизации), во избежании ошибок." Скажите пожалуйста, как бы вы это реализовали (в общих чертах).

Comment: В общих чертах я уже все расписал ..